# kendo grid - cannot reload & have server side validation

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I need to refresh the grid on a grid row add. I do this via the onRequestEnd() which I use to invoke kendoGrid's dataSource read() - Which works.

But I also use server side validation and use the grid's error event to cancel the popup closure - This works, but only if I comment out the onRequestsEnd's dataSource.Read().

Basically I can't do both, the onRequestEnd event fires before the error event, & it doesn't contain any error information, so I cant conditionally do the grid refresh.
Any ideas as to how I can refresh the grid only if the crud (row add) is successful, & have the normal server side validation behaviour.

```
 dataSource ....
    .Events(events => events.Error("myLib.error"))
    .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("myLib.onRequestEnd"))  

 myLib ...  

    error: function (args) {
        if (args.errors) {
            var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();   // cancel popup closure
            });
        }
    },

    // on Grid's DataSource CRUD action completing
    onRequestEnd: function (e) {
        if ((e.type === 'create' || e.type === 'update' || (e.type === 'destroy'))) {
            $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        } 
    },
```

Comment: Have you tried the Change event instead of RequestEnd?

Comment: - i now find the grid is automatically refreshing without the need for the onRequestEnd's dataSource.read() !!. Meaning I can remove the onRefreshEnd event. Problem solved. I was really sure I needed it earlier. but now looks like its re-solved - thank for you assistance.